# Add collectionView to Header

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to add a collectionView to my CollectionView **header**. *A collectionView inside a collectionView I guess*. I've got the header setup and I get a blank collectionView in the header part when I run the app but where can I programme this collectionView.

I've got an outlet for it created in the header.swift file which I can access in my main collectionView file but I can't configure the cells, set the number of sections etc. If it was just a label in the header I could set the text etc here but I'm not sure how to configure a collectionView here.
I tried creating a CollectionViewController file and just linking that to the colectionView in the header but that doesn't work. How can I create a subclass for that collectionView (in the header)?

Swift 3

Answer (score 0):

Okay heres the deal: I guess you use a UICollectionViewController or a UIViewController with a UICollectionView which implements the UICollectionViewDataSource protocol, right? This will massively and unnecessarily bloat your UIViewController.

A better way would be to create a separate object to implment the DataSource of your collection views. One for your main collection view and one for the header collection view. Then you just have to wire them up. You must keep a reference to your data source objects somewhere.

So usually, in viewDidLoad of your view controller you get your collection view and call `collectionView.delegate = theDataSourceObject`.

theDataSourceObject could be a lazy var in your UIViewController `lazy var myDataSourceObject = MyDataSource()`

Then, wherever you create your header collection view, you also set its datasource. I hope you understand what I mean and this answer helps you. If you should learn one thing from it than that your view controllers don't necessarily have to be the datasource and/or the delegate of your UITableView or UICollectionView.

They can be totally different objects. A singleton would be an option as well as storing instance variables of your datasource.